# Issue when debugging with jboss7 maven plugin and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss7.x

When i put a breakpoint i get this message: "Unable to install breakpoint in *** due to missing line number 
attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number 
attributes. "

I have found many answers to resolve this issue, but none of them have solved my problem, and all these answers concern Ant+Eclipse. What would be a solution for Maven+Eclipse?
Thank

I want to make sure that the bug does not come from me. Can someone generate an application from the following archetype:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.archetypes</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

and place a breakpoint?
Thank

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Debug is set in your compiler options for Java:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

Comment: Yes Debug is set to true ( i think it's his default value according to the  documentation, but i have set  explicitly that value to true)